# How to see request data being sent to service in Visual Studio Debug?

Tags: visual-studio, request, httpclient

How can I see the json data actually being sent in Request in Visual Studio to verify it is well formed and troubleshoot if something is wrong with data?

I have a StockItem class with example code:
    public class StockItem
    {
        private string _recID;

```
    [JsonProperty("recid")]
    public string RecID
    {
        get { return _recID; }
        set { _recID = value; }
    }
 )
```

That should set the name of the column being passed to web service to the one matching their column.

```
   public static async Task ProcessItemsAsync(object content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "tokencode");
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, itemUrl))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    request.Content = stringContent;

                    using (var response = await client
                        .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

I look at Locals or Autos in Visual Studio...I can see my StockItem object in content [0]. But not in request.Content.

The reason in response is Bad Request.  How do I troubleshoot this?

The RequestMessage is "Bad Request".  Sorry...I am extremely frustrated with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see the request being sent with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). As far as I know you can't see it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I had been messing around with that...once I added  a new config to solution web.config I was able to see the request.  Thank you very much.      <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
      <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>